# Taking string objects using getline

Tags: c++, string, getline

I am trying to take user input directly from console using getline into a C++ string object. I am however failing to do so as the compiler gives me the following error.

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:52:28: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ifstream<char>::getline(std::ifstream&, std::string&)’
main.cpp:52:28: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:599:5: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::getline(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::char_type*, std::streamsize, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::char_type) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::char_type = char, std::streamsize = int]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:599:5: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:408:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::getline(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::char_type*, std::streamsize) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::char_type = char, std::streamsize = int]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:408:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘int’
```

Here is the source code:

```
#include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>
 #include <cmath>
 #include <cstdlib>
 #include <cstring>
 #include <string>
 #include <map>
 #include <set>
 #include <algorithm>
 #include <cstdio>

 #define MAX_LIN 1024

 using namespace std;

 typedef set<int> si;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
 {   
     string line1;
     string line2;

     map <string , si > iMap;

     if (argc != 3) { 
         fprintf(stderr,"Usage: a.out <file1> <file2>\n");
     }

     ifstream f1,f2;

     f1.open(argv[1],ifstream::in);
     f2.open(argv[2],ifstream::in);

     while(!f1.eof()) {
         getline(f1,line1);
         mParse(line1);
     }   

     while(!f2.eof()) {
         f2.getline(f2,line2);
         mParse(line2);
     }   

     f1.close();
     f2.close();


     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Did you `#include <string>`? Please add your include directives to the posted code, I don't see any.

Comment: Have you done `#include<fstream>` in the header?

Comment: Yes, I have done both. Let me include the entire headers.

Comment: @humanitarian0098: It is a good idea to learn to read compiler messages. They are not always the prettiest, but we do have to deal with them on a daily basis after all. `std::basic_ifstream<char>::getline(std::ifstream&, std::string&)` can also be seen as `std::ifstream::getline(std::ifstream&, std::string&)`, this is the compiler guessing what you were trying to call. Note how it indicates both that: 1/ it is a method of `std::ifstream` that you were calling and 2/ you passed `std::ifstream&` and `std::string&` as parameters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the cause:

```
f2.getline(f2,line2);
```

should be:

```
getline(f2,line2);
```

There is a [`std::ifstream::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) but it accepts different arguments.

Note the structure of the `while` loops is incorrect as `eof()` should be checked immediately after a read operation. A common way of coding the loop is:

```
while (getline(f2, line2))
{
    mParse(line2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the canonical way:

```
 std::ifstream f1(argv[1]);
 std::ifstream f2(argv[2]);

 for (std::string line; std::getline(f1, line); )
 {
     mparse(line);
 }

 for (std::string line; std::getline(f2, line); )
 {
     mparse(line);
 }
```

Note everything we **don't** write, each of which should be considered a capital sin: `eof`, `open`, `close`, `ifstream::in`, `return 0`.